# Вычитание. Длинная арифметика. JS

Tags: javascript, длинная-арифметика

Необходимо реализовать вычитание больших чисел.
Написала функцию, но в консоли выводит с ошибкой: `499999-41900`

```
function sub (a, b) {
  a = a.split('').reverse();
  b = b.split('').reverse();
  var index;
  var c = 0;
  var length = a.length;

  for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    console.log(a[index], b[index], c)
    if (c) {
      a[index] -= (b[index] || 0) + c;
    } else {
      a[index] -= (b[index] || 0);
    }
    a[index] += (c = (a[index] < 0) ? 1 : 0) * 10;
  }
  // Count the zeroes which will be removed
  index = 0;
  length = a.length - 1;
  while (a[length - index] === 0 && length - index > 0) {
    index++;
  }
  if (index > 0) {
    a.splice(-index);
  }
  return a.reverse().join('');
}
console.log(sub('5000000002', '5102'));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: [связанный вопрос со сложением](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470248/186999)

Comment: Попробуй словами описать, что у тебя в коде происходит

Comment: _a[index]_ у тебя - строка, как и _b[index]_. Когда ты складываешь строку с чем-то, у тебя идет сложение строк, и `'4'+0` вернет `'40'`. Для решения просто приведи к числам все символы