# Как вывести большое число как строку в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, строки, числа

Есть два больших числа:

```
var a = 63829983432984289347293874;
```

и

```
var b = 90938498237058927340892374089;
```

мне надо вывести их сумму как строку: `"91002328220491911630239667963"`, но при суммировании у меня получается число с плавающей точкой 9.100232822049192e+28.
Как преобразовать это число с плавающей точкой к строке, которую надо вывести?

Comment: никак, нужно изначально хранить строки и воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой для длинной арифметики. Так же можно [самому реализовать сложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470248/186999)

Comment: Спасибо, реализация сложения самому помогла!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```js
var a = 63829983432984289347293874;
var b = 90938498237058927340892374089;

var stringSum = (a + b).toPrecision(40).split('.')[0]

console.log('stringSum = ', stringSum);
```

Comment: Интересное решение, только мне нужно получить точный результат, как в задаче

Comment: Для тех условий, что представили вы, решение корректно. Если вам нужна дробная часть, уберите `.split('.')[0]` и обрежьте лишние нули или приведите к нужной вам точности. Направление я вам дал. Дальше или дерзайте сами, или уточняйте условия задачи.

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что результат сложения 4+9 ну никак не может оканчиваться на 2, как в вашем примере?

Comment: Посыпаю голову пеплом... На некоторых платформах NaN выдает, как результат сложения. Будет время, разберусь, что к чему и отредактирую ответ, с пометкой, что он не верный и почему.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось точное значение только когда я использовал собственную функцию для сложения больших чисел:

```js
var a = '63829983432984289347293874';
var b = '90938498237058927340892374089';

function res(a, b, result, carry, base) {
  if (a.length == 0 && b.length == 0 && !carry)
    return result;

  var left = parseInt(a.pop() || '0', 10);
  var right = parseInt(b.pop() || '0', 10);

  var l = left + right + (carry || 0);

  return res(a, b, l % base + (result || ""), Math.floor(l / base), base);
}

function add(a, b) {
  return res(a.toString().split(""), b.toString().split(""), "", "", 10).toString();
}

console.log(add(a, b));
```

Comment: Что-то этот код не работает и выдаёт сплошные NaN

Comment: @andreymal, там переменные строками должны быть сразу, а не большими числами